# Converting Strings to unique numerical values Pandas or Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am a beginner in Python and Deep Learning. It might be easy for most of you but how can I do it?

How to convert the below objects into unique numerical values?

```
df['city'].unique()

array(['LIMA', 'VACAVILLE', 'CINCINNATI', 'GLASGOW', 'BOWLING GREEN',
   'LANCASTER', 'HOUSTON', 'SPRINGFIELD', 'RAPID CITY', 'FORT WORTH',
   'LAREDO', 'NEW YORK', 'CHARLESTON', 'PITTSBURGH',
   'WEST VALLEY CITY', 'CAYCE', 'HOT SPRINGS NATIO', 'CANTON',
   'FORT WAYNE', 'DU BOIS', 'DAYTON', 'MASON CITY', 'WASHINGTON',
   'LAKE OSWEGO', 'FAYETTEVILLE', 'SALT LAKE CITY', 'KNOXVILLE',
   'TURLOCK', 'MCALLEN', 'CENTERVILLE', 'ROCHESTER', 'OKLAHOMA CITY',
   'GAUTIER', 'DOYLESTOWN', 'ATLANTA', 'MEADVILLE', 'FORT MYERS',
   'ERIE', 'BEAUMONT', 'JACKSON', 'CLARKSVILLE', 'BETHLEHEM',
   'SAN ANTONIO', 'LAS VEGAS', 'ATHENS', 'SAN LUIS OBISPO', 'SEATTLE',
   'BRADENTON', 'TINLEY PARK', 'HUNTLEY', 'SYRACUSE', 'WHEELWRIGHT',
   'TOWSON', 'YONKERS', 'ARDEN HILLS', 'MARION', 'LIVONIA',
   'COLORADO SPRINGS', 'CURWENSVILLE', 'SAINT CHARLES', 'PETERSBURG',
   'SCOTTSDALE', 'SILVER SPRING', 'PORTLAND', 'BIRMINGHAM',
   'CEDARVILLE', 'CLERMONT', 'ASHEVILLE', 'SHREVEPORT', 'DRAPER',
   'WAVERLY', 'CANANDAIGUA', 'MOUNT PLEASANT', 'MARIETTA', 'MANKATO',
   'HARLINGEN', 'HATCH', 'MOBILE', 'POULSBO', 'GARDEN GROVE',
   'GIG HARBOR', 'OCONOMOWOC', 'MOUNT MORRIS', 'ORLANDO',
   'DODGE CITY', 'DILLSBURG', 'HUNTSVILLE', 'KANSAS CITY',
   'JACKSONVILLE', 'DULUTH', 'CITRUS HEIGHTS', 'ONEONTA', 'LOS LUNAS',
   'GIBSONIA', 'ROBINSON', 'VERNON HILLS', 'PHOENIX', 'DESTIN',
   'SHEPHERD', 'BROOKLYN', 'PLANO', 'WINTERS', 'JAMAICA', 'POWAY',
   'LEXINGTON', 'UPLAND', 'NEW ALBANY', 'GREENVILLE',
   'JEFFERSON CITY', 'ARLINGTON', 'BUFFALO', 'LOS ANGELES',
   'CHARLOTTE', 'WEST LAFAYETTE', 'GARY', 'COOPERSTOWN', 'GREAT BEND',
   'DAVISON', 'SMYRNA', 'MISSOURI CITY', 'MEMPHIS',
   'FORT WALTON BEACH', 'KISSIMMEE', 'BATAVIA', 'OLDSMAR', 'WYNNE',
   'ASHVILLE', 'FT BRAGG', 'TROY', 'SHAKER HTS', 'CLEVELAND HTS',
   'HAMBURG'], dtype=object)
```

I am trying to train a model using this data.

Comment: check questions with one hot encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try [`sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder). As stated in the document, it encodes labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
df['city_num'] = le.fit_transform(df['city'])

print(df.head())
#             city  city_num
# 0           LIMA        72
# 1      VACAVILLE       122
# 2     CINCINNATI        21
# 3        GLASGOW        50
# 4  BOWLING GREEN        10
print(len(df.city.unique()))
# 132
print(len(set(df.city_num)))
# 132
```

You may then convert the numerical column to indicators columns

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ohe = OneHotEncoder()
city_ind = ohe.fit_transform(df.city_num.values.reshape(-1, 1))

print(type(city_ind))
# <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>

print(city_ind.shape)
# (132, 132)

print(city_ind[0:2, ].toarray())
# [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.
#    0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC need [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city':list('abcddf')})
df['city1'] = pd.factorize(df['city'])[0]
```

Or convert to `categorical`s and get [`codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.codes.html):

```
df['city'] = pd.Categorical(df['city'])
df['city1'] = df['city'].cat.codes
```

---

```
print (df)

  city  city1
0    a      0
1    b      1
2    c      2
3    d      3
4    d      3
5    f      4
```